# How much does Attack Boost increase attack power?

Tags: kirby-and-the-forgotten-land

At Waddle Dee's Item Shop you can buy an Attack Boost that increases attack power for 200 seconds. How much does it increase attack power by?

[image: Buying an attack boost]

Comment: This probably needs some data mining, because no online source states the boost amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attack Boost increases attack power by about 50%.

I tested this by going to the weapon shop and testing how many hits it took to defeat Mr. Sandbag using various copy abilities before and after using an Attack Boost.

- Masked Hammer: 39 -> 26 (50% more damage)
- Homing Bomb: 40 -> 27 (48.15% more damage)
- Morpho Knight Sword+★: 51 -> 34 (50% more damage)

Comment: That is actually a damage increase of 50%, which reduce the required number of attacks by 33%.

Comment: @Kruga Percentages corrected